# How do I get HTML elements' bounding boxes on the command line

Tags: html, dom

This is trivial inside the browser, but I am trying to find a way to do this from the command line: how do I get the bounding box of every element in an HTML file, if possible after executing javascript.

Something that does:

```
magic_html_tool foo.html
```

and prints out something looking like this (not picky about the output format):

```
svg1,67.3587,108.957,658.983,724.606
g1,67.3587,108.957,658.983,724.606
g3,67.3587,108.957,658.983,724.606
g2,67.3587,280.44,658.983,553.123
path1,67.3587,280.44,75.0667,19.2067
text1,74.2857,286.284,29.935,6.37638
tspan1,74.2857,286.284,29.935,6.37638
path2,142.269,280.44,58.58,19.2067
path3,200.705,280.44,183.073,19.2067
path4,383.635,280.44,120.793,19.2067
```

which is  id, x, y, width, and height (inkscape does that neatly for SVG, see [here](https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/Using_the_Command_Line#Query_geometry_information)).

I am aware that:

- I'd probably have to define a delay or similar
- and I'd have to define a screen/page size or something similar

I'm willing to do some programming (python, perl, javascript) but **command line** is an absolute requirement.

Comment: Maybe using selenium?  - https://www.selenium.dev/   .  HTML is not like PDF where there are hard coordinates you can find by parsing, you need a full rendering engine that will also process the JS and CSS that modifies the HTML, i.e. a web browser.  It seems very unlikely someone went to that much effort to create a non-browser engine for your use case.